# Class-method in Typescript

Tags: typescript, inheritance, class-method

I want to be able to use a class-based method in Typescript - i.e. a method defined on a base class which, when called on a subclass, can access the subclass from which it was called. This behaviour is possible in Python, but as far as I can tell there is no equivalent in Typescript. What would be the best way to replicate this in Typescript?

**Example (in Python):**

This example (written in Python) demonstrates something I may want to do with this.

```
# Base class
class Model:
    objects = []

    def __init__(self, objId):
        self.objId = objId

        Model.objects.append(self)

    @classmethod
    def getById(cls, objId):
        # Method can access subclass using "cls" parameter
        objects = [obj for obj in cls.objects if obj.objId == objId]
        if len(objects) > 0:
            return objects[0]
        else:
            print("error")

# Subclass
class Foo(Model):
    def __init__(self, objId, name):
        self.objId = objId
        self.name = name

        Foo.objects.append(self)

Foo(1, "foo")
Foo(3, "bar")

# Call method on subclass
foo = Foo.getById(1)
bar = Foo.getById(3)

print(foo.name)  # outputs "foo"
print(bar.name)  # outputs "bar"

Foo.getById(2)  # outputs "error"
```

**Typescript (not working):**

This example shows the rough equivalent in typescript, but it doesn't work because of the lack of class methods.

```
class Model {
    static objects: Model[]

    id: number

    constructor (id) {
        this.id = id

        Model.objects.push(this);
    }

    // Here "cls" should refer to the class on which this method is called
    static getById (id): cls {
        let item = cls.objects.find(obj => obj.id == id);
        if (item === undefined) {
            console.log("error");
        } else {
            return item;
        }
    }
}

class Foo extends Model {
    name: string

    constructor (id, name) {
        super(id);

        this.name = name

        Foo.objects.push(this);
    }
}


new Foo(1, "foo");
new Foo(3, "bar");

// Here cls === Foo
let foo = Foo.getById(1);
let bar = Foo.getById(3);

console.log(foo.name);
console.log(bar.name);

Foo.getById(2)
```

Clearly this is easy to do with a single class, but I can't figure out a way to be able to use a method like this for multiple classes, without re-declaring it on each one.

**Side question:**

Is there any way to have an "objects" static property on each subclass, each typed to their subclass, without manually re-declaring it.

```
class Model {
    static objects: Model[]

class Foo extends Model {
    static objects: Foo[]

class Bar extends Model {
    static objects: Bar[]
```

Essentially, I want this behaviour, but without having to separately declare the "objects" property on each subclass. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `this` context of a static method is the class on which it was called.  You can override the `this` type for `getById` to state that `getById` can be called on any subclass of `Model` (i.e., any object with a construct signature that constructs a subtype of `Model`) and returns the instance type of that class.  Here is example code, assuming that all objects of all subclasses are stored in the single `Model.objects` array:

```
class Model {
    static objects: Model[]

    id: number

    constructor (id) {
        this.id = id

        Model.objects.push(this);
    }

    static getById<M extends Model>(
        this: { new(...args: any[]): M }, id): M {
        let item = Model.objects.find(obj => obj.id == id);
        if (item === undefined) {
            console.log("error");
        } else {
            return <M>item;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this is unsound because someone could call `Foo.getById` with an ID that corresponds to a `Bar` instead of a `Foo`.

If you want a separate `objects` array for each subclass, you'll need to manually initialize the array in each subclass (there is no way to automate this), change the `Model` constructor to push into the `objects` array of the current class (which you can reference as `this.constructor` after declaring it), and then change `getById` to use `this.objects`, after declaring that it must exist.

```
class Model {
    static objects: Model[]
    "constructor": {
        // This implementation is slightly unsound: the element type
        // is actually the instance type of the constructor.  At least
        // the interface provided is safe.
        objects: Model[]
    };

    id: number

    constructor (id) {
        this.id = id

        this.constructor.objects.push(this);
    }

    static getById<M extends Model>(
        this: { new(...args: any[]): M, objects: M[] }, id): M {
        let item = this.objects.find(obj => obj.id == id);
        if (item === undefined) {
            console.log("error");
        } else {
            return item;
        }
    }
}
```